# Split string in multiple places

Tags: python, string

New to programming and currently working with python. I am trying to take a user inputted string (containing letters, numbers and special characters), I then need to split it multiple times at different points to reform new strings. I have done research on the splitting of strings (and lists) and feel I understand it but I still know there must be a better way to do this than I can think of.

This is what I currently have

```
ass=input("Enter Assembly Number: ")
#Sample Input 1 - BF90UQ70321-14
#Sample Input 2 - BS73OA91136-43
ass0=ass[0]
ass1=ass[1]
ass2=ass[2]
ass3=ass[3]
ass4=ass[4]
ass5=ass[5]
ass6=ass[6]
ass7=ass[7]
ass8=ass[8]
ass9=ass[9]
ass10=ass[10]
ass11=ass[11]
ass12=ass[12]
ass13=ass[13]
code1=ass0+ass2+ass3+ass4+ass5+ass6+ass13
code2=ass0+ass2+ass3+ass4+ass5+ass6+ass9
code3=ass1+ass4+ass6+ass7+ass12+ass6+ass13
code4=ass1+ass2+ass4+ass5+ass6+ass9+ass12
# require 21 different code variations
```

Please tell me that there is a better way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: can you able to put an example with taking actual string

Comment: You could try slicing.

Comment: Is there any pattern?

Comment: http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/

Comment: Thanks guys updated the question with input samples.

Comment: Please expand on the logic you are trying to implement to get your 21 different code variations. Are they random? Must they be the same for each input? Are there rules determine what makes a valid code variation?

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to this code and Google "python string slicing" (a nice tutorial for beginners is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqAgMUPRh7U).

String (and list) slicing is used a lot in Python. Be sure to learn it well. The upper index could be not so intuitive, but it becomes second nature.

```
ass="ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"

code1 = ass[0] + ass[2:7] + ass[13]   # ass[2:7] is to extract 5 chars starting from index 2 (7 is excluded)
code2 = ass[0] + ass[3:7] + ass[9]
code3 = ass[1] + ass[4] + ass[6:8] + ass[12] + ass[6] + ass[13]
code4 = ass[1:3] + ass[4:7] + ass[9] + ass[12]
```

PS: You probably need also to check if the string length is 14 before working with it.

**EDIT: Second solution**

Here is another solution, perhaps it is easier to follow:

```
def extract_chars(mask):
    chars = ""
    for i in mask:
        chars += ass[i]
    return chars

mask = [0,2,3,4,5,6,13]
print extract_chars(mask)
```

Here you define a mask of indexes of the chars you want to extract.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping there may have been another way that didn't require defining each instance of code individually. Noted the need to check string length, I left it out to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: @JamesSaunders, you could do it with regex (regular expressions) but if you are a newbie it is better to leave it for a later time.

Comment: @JamesSaunders, I added a second solution. Perhaps it is more intuitive.

Comment: Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
input1 = 'BF90UQ70321-14'
code = lambda anum, pos: ''.join(anum[p] for p in pos)

code4 = code(input1, (1,2,4,5,6,9,12))
```